# Juniper SRX300 cluster

Tags: firewall, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

I'm trying to set up chassis cluster on Juniper SRX300 (Junos 15.1X49-D45).

And I wasn't able to find any documentation on this matter.

I was able to run the command:

```
set chassis cluster cluster-id 0 node 0[1] reboot
```

on both nodes, but after the reboot cluster is not enabled:

```
root> show chassis cluster status
error: Chassis cluster is not enabled.
```

Is the anything else I should do?

Is there any special license required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find full documentation [here](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos15.1x49-d40/information-products/pathway-pages/security/security-chassis-cluster-library.pdf).

You're on the right track, but cluster-id should be greater than 0. From the documentation:

> Setting a cluster ID to 0 is equivalent to disabling a cluster. A
>   cluster ID greater than 15 can only be set when the fabric and control
>   link interfaces are connected back-to-back.

Keep in mind that you need to connect the two SRX300 devices on port ge-0/0/1 (for the control link). In the factory default configuration, this interface is already configured and part of a security zone; you need to remove all configuration relating to this interface before the chassis cluster will form.